# Apache Beam IO in Go: sql: unknown driver "cloudsql-postgres" (forgotten import?)

Tags: postgresql, go, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Following the guide [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-go-connector/blob/main/README.md#postgres), I'm trying to connect a Dataflow job to a Cloud SQL Postgres instance on GCP in Go.

I'm able to run the job locally on my machine. I've verified that my permissions are correct and that the job has the requisite permissions.

The problem is, when I try to run the job, I get the following error:

`Name: github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/io/databaseio.queryFn] failed: failed to open database: cloudsql-postgres caused by: sql: unknown driver "cloudsql-postgres" (forgotten import?)`

This is the code I'm using to connect:

```
func ReadFromPostgres(
    ctx context.Context,
    scope beam.Scope,
    opt *SourceOption,
    secretReader *SecretReader,
    elemType reflect.Type,
    query string,
    postgresDriver string,
) (beam.PCollection, error) {
    cleanup, err := pgxv4.RegisterDriver(postgresDriver, cloudsqlconn.WithIAMAuthN())
    if err != nil {
        return beam.PCollection{}, fmt.Errorf("error connecting to Postgres: %w", err)
    }

    //nolint:all
    defer cleanup()

    scope = scope.Scope("Read from database")

    secret, err := opt.Database.DSN.GetValue(ctx, secretReader)
    if err != nil {
        return beam.PCollection{}, fmt.Errorf("error getting secret value: %w", err)
    }
    envName, location, dbInstanceName, user, dbName := opt.Database.PGEnv.EnvName, opt.Database.PGEnv.Location, opt.Database.PGEnv.DBInstanceName, opt.Database.PGEnv.User, opt.Database.PGEnv.DBName
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s:%s:%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s sslmode=disable", envName, location, dbInstanceName, user, dbName, secret)

    if err != nil {
        return beam.PCollection{}, fmt.Errorf("error getting DSN value: %w", err)
    }

    return databaseio.Query(scope, postgresDriver, dsn, query, elemType), nil
```

Note that "cloudsql-postgres" is argument passed to the postgresDriver parameter I'm passing to the function.

And here are my imports:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
    "cloud.google.com/go/cloudsqlconn"
    "cloud.google.com/go/cloudsqlconn/postgres/pgxv4"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/io/bigqueryio"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/io/databaseio"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
)
```

I would think my driver would be included in the "cloud.google.com/go/cloudsqlconn/postgres/pgxv4" import. Why isn't my driver being properly recognized by the function?

Comment: You should register the driver only once instead of registering it for every query. It panics if a driver is registered more than once (see [the source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/6d1c507bfc360ba72ca716bb7cb7bd9105a45af4/src/database/sql/sql.go#L50-L52)). But I can not find any issue in the posted code which can result in the `sql: unknown driver "cloudsql-postgres" (forgotten import?)` error. Maybe this is not the same code as the one running on GCP? How is your app built and deployed?

Comment: Remember beam is distributed. Its running parts of the function on different processes that havent run your `main` and havent seen the call to `pgxv4.RegisterDriver`.

Sometimes in `ParDo`s you can have a custom `setup` function that can setup a node. If we could put call `RegisterDriver` there it would probably work.

Im not sure how we are supposed to get this to work with `databaseio`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following this documentation on [Connect using Cloud SQL connectors](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-connectors#go_1). Include this in the import

```
import (
        "context"
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net"
        "os"

        "cloud.google.com/go/cloudsqlconn"
        "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
        "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib"
)
```